# How can the multi-core cpu run the program interleaved?

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls

The output of the program are not obviously contents from the `printf()`s in teh code. Instead it looks like characters in irregular sequence. I know the reason is because the parent process and child process are running
at the same time, but in this program I only see `pid=fork()`, which I think means pid is only the id of child process.
So why can the parent process print?
How do the two processes run together?

```
// fork.c: create a new process

#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "user/user.h"

int
main()
{
  int pid;

  pid = fork();

  printf("fork() returned %d\n", pid);

  if(pid == 0){
    printf("child\n");
  } else {
    printf("parent\n");
  }
  
  exit(0);
}
```

output:

```
ffoorrkk(())  rreettuurrnende d 0
    
1c9h

ilpda

rent
```

Comment: Please link to the documentation of `fork()` which you are referring to. It seems that it leaves out a lot of necessary explanation...

Comment: Please quote/show the output you observe. It will make explaining which part of fork()s behaviour in the documentation you use manifests how.

Comment: Thanks! I will see it right now

Comment: It creates two processes and they are executed just as any other process, decided by the OS scheduler.

Comment: I know why cuz the each time fork() is called it will return twice, the parent process will return the id of child process, and child process will return 0(child has no child).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I focus my answer on showing how the observed output can result from the shown program. I think that it will already clear things up for you.

This is your output.
I edited it to use a good guess of what is parent (p) and child (c):

```
ffoorrkk(())  rreettuurrnende d 0\n 
cpcpcpcpcpcpcpcpcpcpcpcpccpcpcppccc

1 c9h\n 
pccpcpp
  
ilpda\n  
ccpcpcc

rent
pppp
```

If you only use the chars with a "c" beneath, you get

```
fork() returned 0
child
```

If you only use the chars with a "p" beneath, you get

```
fork() returned 19
parent
```

Split that way, it should match what you know about how `fork()` works.

Comments already provided the actual answer to the three "?"-adorned questions in title and body of your question post.

Lundin:

> It creates two processes and they are executed just as any other process, decided by the OS scheduler.

Yourself:

> each time fork() is called it will return twice, the parent process will return the id of child process, and child process will return 0

Maybe for putting a more obvious point on it:
The parent process receives the child ID and also continues executing the program after the `fork()`.
That is why the output occurs twice, similarily, interleaved, with differences in PID value and the selected `if` branch.

Relevant is also that in the given situation there is no line buffering. Otherwise there would be no character-by-character interleaving and everthing would be much more readable.

Comment: By the way, why are there so many ’c‘ and ’p‘? 19 should be the id  number instead of times that parent process are runned， I think the letters in 'child' and 'parent' just appears once in random sequence?

Comment: "why are there so many ’c‘ and ’p‘?" I assume a disabled line buffering. With line buffered output, everything would be much more readable.

Comment: "19 should be the id number instead of times that parent process are runned" What makes you think that 19 is a any count? What makes you think that it is not the PID? I recommend to create a separate question discussing those assumptions and expectations.